# clients are continously added to socket due to server assigning ip automatically

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have problem with my code I have only 3 clients(device) which is connected from socket server (node.js). every time my clients disconnected and connected, my clients array length is increasingly it will take up to 50 clients or more.I tried to put the 'end' emitter outside in the 'data' but still it continuously adding the clients.I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I hope someone will help me on this.

```
var net  = require('net');

var clients = [];
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){

    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress; 

    if(!checkArray(socket.name,clients)){
         clients.push(socket);
    }else{
         console.log("client exist");
    }


        socket.on('data',function(data){
        var revdata = data.toString();

        // doSomething(revdata);

     socket.on('end', function () {
        var indexremove = clients.indexOf(socket);
            if (indexremove > -1) {
                clients.splice(indexremove, 1);
                console.log("clients are"+ clients.length);
            }
        });
    });




});

 function checkArray(value, array) {
       return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
   }

server.listen(3020,'127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log("server is up!");
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'the server is automatically assigning ip to the connected socket'??

Comment: NB It doesn't make sense to only add the `end` callback inside the `data` callback, or to do it every time there is data. What if there is no data? or multiple data is received

Comment: Are you sure it *isn't* triggering `end`? It seems to me quite likely that when `end` fires, the remote socket address has disappeared, so the removal from the array may not work. And can you answer my first question?

Comment: If the socket address changes because of the disconnection, and the array removal depends on the original socket address, the socket with the original address won't be removed, because it won't match the present state of the socket. Do you plan to answer my questions any time soon? Two now, and counting.

Comment: No. I asked you two questions 1. What do you mean by 'the server is automatically assigning ip to the connected socket'? 2. Are you sure it *isn't* triggering `end`? You haven't answered either of them.

Comment: **WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY 'GIVE AUTOMATIC IP ADDRESS'?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77683/discussion-between-jemz-and-ejp).

Comment: No, let's answer the question I asked you several hours ago. So that everybody will know what you're talking about.

Comment: I see. It's meaningless, so you just removed it instead. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the bug in your first call to `checkArray`. You're mistakenly using `socket.name` as the first parameter when you should be using `socket` itself. More specifically, for your logic that checks if a client has already connected, try this:

```
if(!checkArray(socket,clients)){
     clients.push(socket);
}else{
     console.log("client exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> the clients increasingly added even I only I have 3 clients(device) because the server is automatically assigning ip to the connected socket.

Yes, that's what TCP/IP does. Underlying all this is a C `getpeername()` function that tells you the remote address of the peer for any connected socket.

> How can I fixed this so that I can only have 3 clients or base on the number of my clients connected to the socket.

*Either:*

1. Your `end` callback isn't being invoked for some reason, which doesn't seem likely (although you're setting it in the wrong place, inside the `data` callback, which assumes you do actually receive some data, and also sets it several times if you receive several chunks)

   *or*
2. The address associated with the socket when `end` is called is already cleared, so your logic to remove that socket from the array doesn't work, if it relies on the socket address being the same as the one in the array. It won't be. So you'll have to use a different data structure, or better still don't have one at all. Most TCP servers only keep track of the current client's socket in the thread or callback that is handling that client: they don't have a global data structure of connected sockets at all. I recommend this alternative to you. There doesn't appear to be any actual purpose to it other than to count the clients, which you can do just as easily with an integer.